# Where is the blog post "Advanced Lightroom Editing – The Adjustment Brush"?

Tags: support, blog

Some days ago there was a blog post from jrista about

```
Advanced Lightroom Editing – The Adjustment Brush
```

Url (http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2012/05/advanced-lightroom-editing-the-adjustment-brush)

I didn't have the chance to read it so i bookmarked it. Now it's gone * sad face *. 
Any reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Released by accident - its still in the works.

Comment: Btw: You Moderation guys do a really great job @ photo.SE. Highly Appreciated!

Comment: @gsharp - Thanks! :)